# Sending an image in python without saving it

Tags: python, image, sockets, pygame, python-imaging-library

I've just started working with PIL and Pygame and I wanted to create a screen-sharing program.
In order to take a screenshot I used ImageGrab.grab() and now I want to send it to another computer and open it in Pygame without saving it on any of the computers.
This is my server right now:

```
#region - - - - - - I M P O R T S - - - - - -
import socket
import select
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pickle
#endregion
#region - - - - - - C O N S T A N T S - - - - - -
PORT = 8253
CONCURRENT_USERS = 5
#endregion
#region - - - - - - M E T H O D S - - - - - -
def CaptureScreen():
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    return img
#endregion
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('', PORT))
server_socket.listen(CONCURRENT_USERS)
clients_list = []
while True:
    read, write, error = select.select([server_socket] + clients_list, [], [], 0)
    for i in read:
        if i is server_socket:
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            clients_list.append(client_socket)
        for i in clients_list:
            img = CaptureScreen()
            try:
                i.send(pickle.dumps(img))
            except socket.error:
                clients_list.remove(i)
                i.close()
```

I tried using pickle in order to send the images but I got an error in response.
So I am looking for a way to send an image I've captured using ImageGrab through sockets and open it with Pygame on another computer without saving it on any of the computers.
Can anyone help me? I'm using Python 2.6 and Windows 7.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the raw image's data with `Image.tobytes()` and rebuild it from raw data with `Image.frombytes()`, cf http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes and http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.fromstring

`Pickle` is a notoriously unsafe protocol FWIW so better to stick with raw data.

Note that these are features from version 2.x of the [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/about.html#why-a-fork) fork of PIL. If you are using the original PIL library and cannot update to Pillow, you'll have to either use the `Image.tostring()` and `Image.fromstring()` methods, or use the `save()` and `load()` functions with a `StringIO` as file object, as (roughly) documented [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.fromstring). As mentioned by jsbueno, this last solution could save quite some bandwidth...

Comment: I get an "AttributeError: tobytes" error, when I'm trying to use:
img.tobytes()
same goes with Image.frombytes(args)
Perhaps I'm using them in a wrong way? can you give me an example for a proper use?

Comment: Also, this will send the raw image data, which is _huge_ - by using the StringIO/(BytesIO) approach you can encode the image to .png or .jpg prior to sending it and save  a lot (up to 90%) in bandwidth,

Comment: The Pygame window is crashing everytime I try to run the code.
I think I may have used the functions wrong.
In the server I have used:
img = ImageGrab.grab() |
img_str = StringIO(img) |
i.send(img_str.getvalue())
--
and in the client:
str_img = '' |
chunk = client_socket.recv(1024) |
while chunk: |
str_img += chunk |
chunk = client_socket.recv(1024) |
img = Image.open(StringIO(str_img)) |
--
(Every '|' is a new line)
Have I done anything wrong? if not, do you have any idea of why this might happen?

Comment: @PyStudent51 you should have a traceback... At least if you run your pygame program from the command line.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I don't get any traceback I'm affraid... (I've tried running it from the command line).
Is there a way that I can send you the full code so you can take a look? (It's not long ~60 lines).
If you agree, in which way to you want me to send the code to you?

Comment: Not a Window user so I won't be able to run your code.